# Load json Kinetics 4.3.3

Tags: kineticjs

I'm trying to load stage.load stage with the function () 4.3.3 kineticjs but no such function is used Kinetic.Node.create. I do not know how to use this function someone could explain how it is used. thank you very much

Comment: please provide a sample of code

Answer (score 0):

Creating a stage from JSON is not complex:

1. Download the serialized json stage.
2. Hydrate the stage with `var stage = Kinetic.Node.create(myJSON, 'container');`

Here is some example code:

```
// Use jQuery to call to your server and retrieve 
// the JSON representation of your KineticJS stage
// jQuery make calling JSON easy, but...
// Alternatively, you can use straight javascript--google ;)
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'http://www.yourSite.com/yourStageInJSON.json',
    success: successHandler,
    error: errorHandler
});

// this is called when your json-stage has been downloaded
function successHandler(myJSON){
    // use the downloaded json to create the stage
    // "container" is just the normal KineticJS container div
    var stage = Kinetic.Node.create(myJSON, 'container');
}

// this is called if there was a problem with the download
function errorHandler(){
    alert("Something has gone horribly wrong--call somebody!");
}
```

If you want to see what a stage serialized to json looks like you can serialize an existing stage like this:

```
var json = stage.toJSON();
```